# AngularJSのバリデーションエラーを非表示にする

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJSは、バリデーションチェックでエラー表示する事ができますが
そのエラー表示を数秒後、自動的に非表示にする事ができるのでしょうか？

もし出来るのあれば方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularでDOM操作をするならカスタムディレクティブを作りましょう。
以下は、入力が8文字を超えるとエラーを表示し、2秒後に非表示にするサンプルです。
アニメーションにjQueryを使用しています。

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('formController', function($scope){
  $scope.maxlength = 8;
})
.directive('fadeOutMessage', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      show: '=',
      message: '@'
    },
    template: '<div style="color:red">{{message}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      var $div = elem.find('div');
      $div.hide();
      scope.$watch('show', function(newVal){
        if(newVal){
          $div.show()
          .delay(1000)
          .fadeOut(1000);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <form name="form" ng-controller="formController">
    <p>maxlength: {{maxlength}}</p>
    <label>Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-maxlength="maxlength"ng-model="name" />
    <fade-out-message show="form.name.$error.maxlength" message="Too long"></fade-out-message>
  </form>
</body>
```